# Strange - jQuery .hover() called on select click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Strange problem that I can't seem to fix..

I have a menu which appears/disappears on mouse enter/leave - bound using jQuery's hover function:

```
$("#sclogo").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast');
    },
    function(){  
        $(this).find("ul.subnav").fadeOut('slow');
    }
);
```

and the menu structure:

```
<ul class='topnav' id='sclogo'>  
    <li><img border='0' src='images/menu.png'/>  
        <ul class="subnav">     
            <li>...</li>
            <li>... </li>
        </ul>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now the problem - clicking on any form select element (which does not have an id or class) triggers the hover function and the menu appears...

Any ideas anyone?

Using jQuery-1.9

UPDATE:
I've just realised that this doesn't occur in Firefox.. but it does in Chromium Version 24.0.1312.69 (180721)
Haven't checked other browsers yet.
If anyone wants to check out the problem - see http://www.ucrewconnect.com.au/test.html

ANOTHER UPDATE:
Confirming this is just a Chromium bug - have tested other browsers and it doesn't occur.. so I'm just going to ignore this.
Sorry to waste anyones time!

Comment: any form select element inside of sclogo?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: negative - no form elements inside sclogo. will try in a fiddle.. never used fiddle before

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Chrome 24.0.1312.57 m. Could be a chromium bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirming this is just a Chromium bug - have tested other browsers and it doesn't occur.. so I'm just going to ignore this. Sorry to waste anyones time!